# route ip packet based on string variable

Tags: java, tcp

All,
Not sure whether to create some Java code or use an 'off-the-shelf' product to produce a listener / router / redirector, one which will listen to a single incoming IP stream and then 'redirect' packets based on a fixed position string variable to an appropriate TCP server.

i.e. If the incoming packet has variable = 1 redirect to a TCP server at 192.168.150.211, if a 2 then redirect to TCP server at 192.168.150.212.

Ideally the code / product should also be able to pre-launch multiple TCP servers (either at one IP address and different IP ports or at different IP addresses) on the same machine prior to the listener / router starting.

Was thinking of using an OPC server but these seem too complex / costly for a single, relatively slow, incoming stream.

Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: You can write this yourself. Open a ``ServerSocket``, examine the String variable, then use Threads to forward the streams. You probably won't find an already existing tool when your String variable is something you place in the stream by yourself.

Comment: Thanks f1sh, much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the depth of analyzing. If you would like to analyze each packet at TCP-level then low-level language like **C**  will be the best choice: just listen everything that comes to *eth0* (or whatever interface), search for specific string (BTW "string" definition is too wide. The times when a string could be considered as ready-to-process data are in the '80s. Nowadays string is a piece of rubbish until you know what encoding is, how lines are terminated, etc).

As already mentioned by [@f1sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799112/route-ip-packet-based-on-string-variable#comment78556191_45799112) you can redirect traffic using Java. But Java operates with streams, it knowns nothing about network packets. Also, in Java you can listen only on certain port(s) - there is no way to filter on the whole network interface (but [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) can be real saver).

If you would like to get PoC without huge amount of coding lets consider [Socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/). Socat can not only transmit data from one socket to another. It can also write data to files. So you can combine **Socat** (don't forget about `fork` option), **tail**, **grep** and a bit of Bash stuff and get simple redirection server working.

Comment: Thanks flaz14, we already use a multi-threaded TCP client written in java (that would connect to the various servers to receive their appropriate packets) so we want to stay with java throughout for this one. I came across portforward (https://github.com/sharneng/portforward) which I am investigating.